# Shaky Google Maps Marker Animation

Tags: android, google-maps, animation, google-maps-markers

I am attempting to animate markers on a Google Map. The issue that I am running into is how the markers are behaving when it is time for them to animate. The markers are moving along a given set of points, but they start shaking rather violently, or they will move along a set path and appear to be rubberbanding, or jumping back to the original start position.

**Has anyone dealt with this issue before? and if so, how did you fix it?** I am currently using a somewhat modified version of code that was provided by Google devs to handle animation.

UPDATE: **I believe the issue is caused by trying to run many animations simultaneously on a given Marker. This is causing the marker to bounce back and forth between all the new/old positions.**

Here is the code that handles the Animation calls, the method is passed a list of LatLngs which represent the path the marker should follow.

```
public void animateMarker(String key, List<LatLng> latlngList) {
    AnimateCarObj animateCarObj = animateCarObjMap.get(key);
    Marker marker = markersHashMap.get(key);

    if (marker != null) {

        LatLng prev = new LatLng(0, 0);
        for (LatLng latlng : latlngList) {
            if (!(latlng.equals(prev))) {
                try {
                    LatLngInterpolator latlonInter = new LinearFixed();
                    latlonInter.interpolate(1, animateCarObj.getGps1(), latlng);

                    MarkerAnimation.animateMarker(latlngList.size(), marker, latlng, latlonInter);
                    prev = latlng;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "EXCEPTION: " + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MarkerAnimation Class**, I modified this class to take an Integer value called "steps", this is so that the animation will pass through all the points at an even pace regardless of how many points are returned through a request. In this example, it uses a default value of 3, multiplies it by 10000 ms, and than divides it by the step count.

```
public class MarkerAnimation {

    public static void animateMarker(int steps, final Marker marker, final LatLng finalPosition,
                                                                        final LatLngInterpolator latLngInterpolator) {
        if (marker == null || finalPosition == null || latLngInterpolator == null) { return; }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1) {
            animateMarkerToGB(steps, marker, finalPosition, latLngInterpolator);
        } else {
            animateMarkerToICS(steps, marker, finalPosition, latLngInterpolator);
        }
    }

    public static void animateMarkerToGB(int steps, final Marker marker, final LatLng finalPosition,
                                                                                final LatLngInterpolator latLngInterpolator) {
        final LatLng startPosition = marker.getPosition();
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        final Interpolator interpolator = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();
        final float durationInMs = (CarListStore.DEFAULT_ALIVE_COUNT * 10000) / steps;

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            long elapsed;
            float t;
            float v;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Calculate progress using interpolator
                elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                t = elapsed / durationInMs;
                v = interpolator.getInterpolation(t);

                marker.setPosition(latLngInterpolator.interpolate(v, startPosition, finalPosition));

                // Repeat till progress is complete.
                if (t < 1) {
                    // Post again 16ms later.
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /*  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        public static void animateMarkerToHC(final Marker marker, final LatLng finalPosition,
                                                                                    final LatLngInterpolator latLngInterpolator) {
            final LatLng startPosition = marker.getPosition();

            ValueAnimator valueAnimator = new ValueAnimator();
            valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    float v = animation.getAnimatedFraction();
                    LatLng newPosition = latLngInterpolator.interpolate(v, startPosition, finalPosition);
                    marker.setPosition(newPosition);
                }
            });
            valueAnimator.setFloatValues(0, 1); // Ignored.
            valueAnimator.setDuration(3000);
            valueAnimator.start();
        }*/

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    public static void animateMarkerToICS(int steps, Marker marker, LatLng finalPosition, final LatLngInterpolator latLngInterpolator) {
        TypeEvaluator<LatLng> typeEvaluator = new TypeEvaluator<LatLng>() {
            @Override
            public LatLng evaluate(float fraction, LatLng startValue, LatLng endValue) {
                return latLngInterpolator.interpolate(fraction, startValue, endValue);
            }
        };
        Property<Marker, LatLng> property = Property.of(Marker.class, LatLng.class, "position");
        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(marker, property, typeEvaluator, finalPosition);
        animator.setDuration((CarListStore.DEFAULT_ALIVE_COUNT * 10000) / steps);
        animator.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making Asynchronous calls right now and since you have multiple animation on maker you are facing jitters.

Use synchronized method instead i.e `[valueAnimator][1]` - you have it commented out in your code. Watch [this video](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#video_animating_markers) in the docs, it explains why and when to use it.

Hope it helped!

Comment: So the value animator is a Synchronized method? If I loop through a list of coords and call that method for each one, it will run them in a sequence?

Comment: Yeah that's right. Pay attention here: `AnimatorUpdateListener()`. And from the video "`onAnimationUpdate` override, it gets invoked as the next frame is being prepared."  I suggest you watch the video as they discuss three different methods for animation handling.

Comment: Sorry, just to be clear, it will run the *animation frames* in sequence for the coord retrieved by `getPosition`. Also by "run them" do you mean run each marker animation in sequence? If so, I doubt it but I'll get back to you on that.

Comment: Yea so for example, If I pass a list of LatLng Coords, it will animate from 1 to 2, 2 to 3, 3 to 4, etc. I just dont want it to keep bouncing as if it is trying to animate the marker with 6 different LatLng positions at the same time.

Comment: So it will move from 1 to 2, 2 to 3 and so forth for **respective maker** only. And I think what you want is to run the animation one marker at a time, hope I'm right. If you want the animation to run one marker at a time. Set different delays for alternate positions or something. If you want the animation to trigger only for one (supposedly) active marker on map, there's a way but I am not familiar with it. I can let ya know if I can find it though.

Answer (score 0):

My method is to schedule a Runnable using handler such that it can have some callback to call to notify animation is complete. Maintain a linked list for queueing marker position as soon as you get `OnComplete` callback from last animation handler delayed runnable pop the next latlng object from the queue and run the animation.

In each animation method for ICS & HC after `animator.start()` register delayed runnable using `handler.postDelayed()` where the delay is exact duration of the animation